# Issue transitioning to EXPORT_OK from EXPORT

Tags: perl, exporter

According to [Perl Critic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Modules/ProhibitAutomaticExportation.pm) we should "Export symbols via `@EXPORT_OK` or `%EXPORT_TAGS` instead of `@EXPORT`"

Following this advice I am transitioning my module to `@EXPORT_OK` from `@EXPORT`, but I am having difficulty with functionality around `Exporter`. Below I will give an illustrative example of the situation.

### Original Code

Originally my code looked like this and it worked as expected:

*lib/MyAnimals/Cats.pm*

```
package MyAnimals::Cats;

use parent qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(tabby calico abyssinian tiger panther leopard);
```

*lib/MyAnimals/Dogs.pm*

```
package MyAnimals::Dogs;

use parent qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(dachshund poodle great_dane st_bernard);
```

*lib/MyAnimals.pm*

```
package MyAnimals;

$Exporter::Verbose = 0;

sub import {
    my $self   = shift;
    my $caller = caller;

    foreach my $package (@_) {
        my $full_package = "MyAnimals::$package";
        eval "require $full_package";
        if ($@) {
            warn "Could not require MyAnimals::$package: $@";
        }

        $full_package->Exporter::export($caller);
    }
    return;
}

=head2 How it works

The MyAnimals module simply imports functions from MyAnimals::* modules.
Each module defines a self-contained functions, and puts those function
names into @EXPORT. MyAnimals defines its own import function, but that
does not matter to the plug-in modules.

This function is taken from brian d foy's Test::Data module. Thanks brian!
```

This allowed me to have in my program:

*program.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use MyAnimals qw(Cats Dogs);
```

Which imported all of the cats and dogs (functions) into the program.

### New Code

However, since it is considered bad form to pollute a user's namespace by exporting everything instead of just what they asked for, I am moving to this code:

*lib/MyAnimals/Cats.pm*

```
package MyAnimals::Cats;

use parent qw(Exporter);

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (house => [qw(tabby calico abyssinian)], jungle => [qw(tiger panther leopard)]);

Exporter::export_ok_tags('house');   # add tabby calico abyssinian to @EXPORT_OK
Exporter::export_ok_tags('jungle');  # add tiger panther leopard to @EXPORT_OK

# add all the other ":class" tags to the ":all" class, deleting duplicates
 {
   my %seen;

   push @{$EXPORT_TAGS{all}},
     grep {!$seen{$_}++} @{$EXPORT_TAGS{$_}} foreach keys %EXPORT_TAGS;
 }
```

*lib/MyAnimals/Dogs.pm*

```
package MyAnimals::Dogs;

use parent qw(Exporter);

our @EXPORT = qw(dachshund poodle great_dane st_bernard);

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (small => [qw(dachshund poodle)], big => [qw(great_dane st_bernard)]);

Exporter::export_ok_tags('small');   # add dachshund poodle to @EXPORT_OK
Exporter::export_ok_tags('big');     # add great_dane st_bernard to @EXPORT_OK

# add all the other ":class" tags to the ":all" class, deleting duplicates
 {
   my %seen;

   push @{$EXPORT_TAGS{all}},
     grep {!$seen{$_}++} @{$EXPORT_TAGS{$_}} foreach keys %EXPORT_TAGS;
 }
```

This now allows my program to import only the animals it wants:

*program.pl*

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use MyAnimals::Cats qw(:jungle tabby);
use MyAnimals::Dogs qw(:big);
```

### Problem

However, I have lost the functionality of `MyAnimals.pm`, specifically I no longer have a simple, clean way of importing eveything in those cases where I really want to, say in a test for example:

*t/01-no_longer_works.t*

```
use MyAnimals qw(Cats Dogs);
```

Now I have to do this:
*t/02-works_but_is_not_elegant.t*

```
use MyAnimals::Cats qw(:all);
use MyAnimals::Dogs qw(:all);
```

### Question

What I am looking for is a way to change `MyAnimals.pm` so that the test `t/01-no_longer_works.t` functions as it previously did (when I was using @EXPORT) and imports all of the animals (functions).

Answer (score 5):

First, don't inherit from Exporter (unless you are making a fancier and more specific exporter yourself). It's enough to get its `import` routine:

```
use Exporter qw(import);
```

Next, it looks like most of your problem is that you want to export from `MyAnimals::Cats` through `MyAnimals` to the final caller. That's something that I'd typically try to avoid. It's fine to play around with this sort of thing, but I'd hate to have to deal with that in production code.

Having said that, `Exporter` has another routine, `export_to_level`, that allows you to export further up the chain. With this you can effectively skip that `MyAnimals` and export to whatever called `MyAnimals`.

Here's `MyAnimals`, in which you have to define your own `import` and do a lot of work. Remember that you can't just ask every module to import everything because they only export their own stuff (although you can goof around by them having the same export tags I guess). I've left all that bookkeeping and fiddling out of this:

```
package MyAnimals;

sub import {
    shift;
    require MyAnimals::Cats;
    MyAnimals::Cats->import( @_ );
    }

1;
```

Now, `MyAnimals::Cats`, which is now a specialized importer so it inherits from `Exporter`. You can't get to `export_to_level` otherwise:

```
package MyAnimals::Cats;
use parent qw(Exporter);
```

You may also like to look at the source for `Modern::Perl` to see how it imports a bunch of things from different sources.

```
sub import {
    __PACKAGE__->export_to_level(2, @_);
    }

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo bar);

sub foo { print "foo from Cats\n"; }
sub bar { print "bar from Cats\n"; }

1;
```

And then the test program, which only loads `MyAnimals` and asks for two things:

```
use lib qw(.);
use MyAnimals qw(foo bar);

foo();
bar();
```

The output shows that I got what I wanted:

```
$ perl test.pl
foo from Cats
bar from Cats
```

But, this is not a good design if there's any other way you could get this to work. There are various things to recognize the modules that you want to load and then call their import routines with the `:all` tag like you have shown. However, you are back to where you started where you are exporting everything anyway. If you are going to do that, just more complicated, save yourself the trouble by doing nothing at all.

And remember, there is no such thing as a best practice with no context. *Perl Best Practices* was never meant to be hard and fast rules (read Damian's intro again). Do what makes sense for the problem at hand. There are many cases where I'd rather have default exports that I can turn off rather than things I have to enable every time:

```
use File::Basename;             # I probably want the usual suspects (common)
use File::Basename qw();        # I want nothing (more rare)
use File::Basename qw(dirname); # I want one thing only; this is the code either way
```

Part of Perl's philosophy was to make the things you do all the time easy (less typing), while still giving you a way to do the things you do rarely. This gets lost for the people who want to make all code look alike no matter the intent of the code.

Comment: Brian, Thanks for your reply.  What I was trying to accomplish is to have the benefits of `@EXPORT_OK` (allowing the user to select what they want to import) while still having the ability to import everything in a selected module(s) from the base module.  I wouldn't want to import everything from every sub module, just those I select.  So `use MyAnimals qw(birds fish);` would give the equivalent of importing `:all`  from each of the birds and fish modules without importing anything from cats or dogs.  Basically, I want your original code to import each package with `:all`.

Comment: As to inheriting from Exporter, I originally had `our @ISA = qw(Exporter);` which PBP said to "@ISA used instead of 'use parent'".   I changed this to `use Exporter qw(import);` as you suggested and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Identifying the problem**

> I am transitioning my module to `@EXPORT_OK` from `@EXPORT`

Using `@EXPORT_OK` forces a module's user to explicitly list what it imports from a module. This allows someone reading, debugging or changing the code to quickly see from where an imported symbol originates.

With your module, the caller would use the following to import a symbol from MyAnimals::Cat or MyAnimals::Dog.

```perl
use MyAnimals qw( X );
```

But that's already means "load module MyAnimals::X". It's incompatible to have it "import symbol X" as well.

Fundamentally, the problem you are facing is an interface design failure.

---

**Example design solution**

What if a leading `::` denotes a package to load, and an absence denotes a symbol (or tag) to import? With that interface, one could use the following:

```perl
use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat );
use MyAnimals qw( ::Dog );
use MyAnimals qw( meow );
```

or

```perl
use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog meow );
```

---

**Implementation of example design solution**

```perl
package MyAnimals;

use Exporter   qw( );
use List::Util qw( uniq );

our @EXPORT_OK = ();
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );  # Optional.

sub import {
   my $class = shift;

   my ( @pkgs, @rest );
   for ( @_ ) {
      if ( /^::/ ) {
         push @pkgs, __PACKAGE__ . $_;
      } else {
         push @rest, $_;
      }
   }

   for my $pkg ( @pkgs ) {
      my $mod = ( $pkg =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm";
      require $mod;

      my $exports = do { no strict "refs"; \@{ $pkg . "::EXPORT_OK" } };
      $pkg->import( @$exports );
      @EXPORT_OK = uniq @EXPORT_OK, @$exports;
   }

   @_ = ( $class, @rest );
   goto &Exporter::import;
}

1;
```

So if the "sub modules" look like this

```perl
package MyAnimals::Cat;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( meow );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );  # Optional.

sub meow { print "meow\n"; }

1;
```

```perl
package MyAnimals::Dog;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( woof );
our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( ALL => \@EXPORT_OK );  # Optional.

sub woof { print "woof\n"; }

1;
```

you get output like this

```
$ perl -I lib -e'
   use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog meow woof );
   meow;
   woof;
'
meow
woof
```

Comment: ikegami, this is exactly the kind of thing I was trying to accomplish.  I have been testing this code and it seems that `Cat` and `Dog`  are successfully required and everything they have in their `@EXPORT_OK` are pulled into MyAnimals.  If I call a function `meow` from `Cat` in `MyAnimals` it works (Normally I wouldn't ever call a function from a sub module in the base module as it is only used for loading submodules, but as a test of the code I did).  However the  original caller `t/03-meow_test.t` which has `use MyAnimals qw(::Cat)` returns `Undefined subroutine &main::meow called at ...`

Comment: No, it works fine. Demo now included.

Comment: (Replaced `"::" . EXPORT_OK` with `"::EXPORT_OK"`, but that has no effect except to satisfy strict.)

Comment: ikegami I am still seeing `Undefined subroutine &main::meow called at t/02-new_meow.t line 18.`  I don't see what is causing the problem. I created a project on github to demonstrate:  https://github.com/mattmartini/MyAnimals  Please take a look.

Comment: You didn't import `meow`...

Comment: I may have found the issue.  Your test did `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog meow woof );`  explicitly importing meow and woof, whereas mine was `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog);`  What I was expecting was that by using `::Cat` that the equivalent of `:all` (in this case `meow`) would be imported by the caller.  Which is the point of the exercise.  How do I get `:all` to be imported?

Comment: The whole point of using `@EXPORT_OK` is to forcing the module's user to specify its imports! My whole answer is about switching the module to use `@EXPORT_OK`, as stated in the question ("Following this advice I am transitioning my module to `@EXPORT_OK` from `@EXPORT`")

Comment: You could use `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog :ALL );`, but that defies the point of using `@EXPORT_OK`, which is that you know exactly from where a symbol originates.

Comment: Yes, I want to use `@EXPORT_OK` so the user can ask for only the imports they want, but in the case when I want everything `::Cat` would be the same as specifying `use MyAnimals::Cat qw(:all)`  It is a nice shorthand when you have many sub modules to import.  See my original question the *Problem* section (althought at that point I didn't use `::`)

Comment: Again, using `:ALL` defies the whole point of using `@EXPORT_OK`. /// If you just want to make changes that do absolutely nothing, don't make the changes! You don't need my help for that. /// And again, I recommend using `:ALL` instead of `:all` to be consistent with "built-in" `:DEFAULT` (which exports everything in `@EXPORT`)

Comment: Your *Problem* section says that `use MyAnimals::Cats qw(:all); use MyAnimals::Dogs qw(:all);` is inelegant. I solved that.

Comment: `:ALL` is fine with me.  However, `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog :ALL );` or `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog meow woof );` kind of defeats the purpose.  In my real project, I have many submodules which in turn have many functions.  I moved from `@EXPORT` to `@EXPORT_OK` so I didn't have to import everything when it was not needed.  BUT when I do want to import everything I want `::CAT` to implicitly mean `MyAnimals::Cat qw(:all)`

Comment: Re "*kind of defeats the purpose*", Backwards. Not doing `use MyAnimals qw( ::Cat ::Dog meow woof );` defies the purpose of using `@EXPORT_OK`. If you don't want to use `@EXPORT_OK`, don't!

Comment: I repeat: If you don't want any changes, don't make any changes. This is my last interaction with this question, answer and their comments.

Comment: By adding `@EXPORT = uniq @EXPORT, @$exports;` to `MyAnimals.pm` I was able to achieve my original goal.  I have updated my github project (see comment above)to reflect a working prototype.  Now my program can `use MyAnimals::Cats (meow);` to only import `meow` and it can also use `use MyAnimals qw(::Cats ::Dogs);` to import everything from both `MyAnimals::Cats` and `MyAnimals::Dogs`.  This is especially useful when there are many sub modules.

Comment: Finally,  now we have complete flexibility:   `use MyAnimals::Dogs  qw(woof);` for a single import, `use MyAnimals::Birds qw(:sounds);` for a tagged set, and `use MyAnimals        qw(::Cats ::Dogs ::Birds);` for everything.

Comment: Why are you using `::Cats` and `::Dogs` instead of `Cats` and `Dogs`????? That makes no sense. Also, that will cause a lot of warnings if someone does `use MyAnimals qw( Cats ); use MyAnimals qw( Dogs );` as one would expect to be able to do. And why are you posting this on my answer??? These last two comments do not pertain to it.